# Issue with "blanking screen" when running Qt application in fullscreen mode

Tags: windows, qt, fullscreen, qwidget, qtwebengine

We have a Qt based browser application which uses QWebEninge under the hood. Currently we are fighting with an issue where the screen goes blank for a moment eacht time the window gets or looses the focus (f.ex. each time the QVirtualKeyboard becomes invoked). Following a [Qt's recommendation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebengine-platform-notes.html), we tried to implement `QWindowsWindowFunctions::setHasBorderInFullScreen` prior to call of `QMainWindow::showFullScreen()`. But this results in an inacceptable reduction of the available window area, e.g. 1918x1078 instead of 1920x1080 (this fix adds WS_BORDER to the window flags).

During some experiments if found out that the problem also - and only - occours, if I use `QMainWindow::show()` while setting the window's size in a way that it exactly matches the screen's resolution. With other words: Going beyond the screen's bounds isn't a problem. Therefore, my idea was to get such a `WS_BORDER` around my QMainWinow and size/place it in a way so that the availabe area covers the screen.

My questions are:

- Is there a better solution to get rid of this?
- If not: How can I get a `WS_BORDER` for a "normal" `QMainWinodw`? I tried to use `Get/SetWindowLongPtr(QMainWindow::winId(), GWL_STYLE/GWL_EXSTYLE)` both before and after call of `QMainWinodw::show()`, but this didn't help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note: I already noticed that graphics drivers plays an important role here. The system in scope has an Intel HD Graphics 5xx GPU, drivers are up to date. Same happened on another computer with Intel HD Graphics 6xx GPU. Also changing "Advanced Graphics settings" in Windows settings to "High performance" did not help.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround I tried to placed a hidden (opaque) mini window (0x0px) using Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint - that worked. If anyone knows a better solution please let us know. Thanks.

**EDIT**
It was a accidental finding: The magnifier tool from Windows was active for some reason and i noticed that the problem does not occurr when the magnifier is in front of my applications Windows. As a conclusion of that, I tried to place an "always on top" window and could see that it worked. In the end I wanted to hide this "overlay", which was done by setting it's width/height to 0px/0px.
However, it seems there are some generic issues regarding Qt and the Intel HD Graphics adapter of the system in scope. As far as I remember, the issue only occurs whe the (fullscreen) window's size mathces the geometry of the display - resizing it by at least on pixel beyond the display's geometry helped, but this was no option in our case.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your solution?

Comment: @JoanVenge: Did the edit answer your question?

Comment: I didnt see your edit before. I just read it, so you have to resize the fullscreen window 1 more pixel? The issue I have is also related to intel drivers, I am unable to fix the issue.

Comment: Yes, using a frameless Windows that exceeds the screens boundary by at least 1px is one possible solution. The other is to make your main window fullscreen as you did before and place a second "mini window" that uses the AlwaysOnTopHint in front. However - as stated in the proposal - this is more a workaround than a solution.

Comment: I used your workaround and it seems to work but when I do Windows Key + D to show desktop and then come back to my main qt window, it still blanks out, even though the decoy always_on_top window is there too. Do you parent one to the other? Or does it not matter? Basically always on top window still goes away when I do WinKey + D. Not sure how you managed to make it robust.